# How can I get the basic prompt for adding CRUD [Create Read Update Destroy] to a new controller in Visual Studio ASP.NET in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am following a tutorial for ASP.NET MVC3.  My local environment is MVC5 in Visual Studio Premium 2013, version 12.
I would like to now add a new controller.
The tutorial shows the ability to add CRUD action methods by simply checking a box entitled *"Add action methods for Create, update, delete, and Details scenarios"*
as seen here:
[image]

In my current setup, the Add Controller prompt now looks as follows:
[image]

Which of these options best mimics the MVC3 default CRUD checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, under the dropdown for Template, *MVC Controller with empty read/write actions* will generate the Create, Update, and Details methods desired without further specifying any library extensions.

[image]